# jQuery Character Counter using class?

Tags: jquery

I have a rather long form with textareas fields and I'd like to use a class selector instead of an ID to identify the fields and limits for each field.  Right now, I have this working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#TextAreaID").counter({
        goal: 500
    });
});
```

and this works for one textarea but since I have several textarea's, I'd like to know a better way to do this since this doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".limit500").counter({
        goal: 500
    });
});
```

I'm using this jQuery Plugin:  http://meetups.jquery.com/profiles/blogs/jquery-word-and-character

Comment: I asked a follow up question which can be viewed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961837/character-counter-with-a-dynamic-limit-using-jquery-each

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the elements and apply `.counter` to each:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".limit500").each(function() {
        $(this).counter({
            goal: 500
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  +1 if you can explain to me what the .each function is doing in simple English.  I've reviewed the jquery docs but they aren't clearing it up for me.

Comment: The `each` function iterates over each item that's matched by the selector, calling the specified callback. Within the callback `this` is set to the DOM object of the current item.

Comment: I just added console.log(this) in the .each loop and saw what was being evaluated.  That is very cool!  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I just thought of another question.  I see that my DOM object is `<textarea rows="2" class="input-xlarge limit500" id="field1" name="field1"></textarea>`  If I were to say use data-content such that the DOM object was actuall `<textarea rows="2" class="input-xlarge limit500" id="Blinds" name="Blinds" data-content="1000"></textarea>` could I pull out the 1000 from the data-content and use that as the character counter limit?  That way I wouldn't have to have separate classes for each limit?

Comment: "how" would probably be beyond the scope of this question so I'll open another question.  Thanks again for confirming it was possible.

Comment: No problem. Check out [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply the `counter()` to each element (totally untested) -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.limit500').each(function() {
        $(this).counter({
            goal: 500
        });
    });
});
```