# Character Counter with a dynamic limit using jQuery .each()

Tags: jquery

This question is an extension of [jQuery Character Counter using class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959314/jquery-character-counter-using-class).

I would like to add a `data-content="####"` to my textarea field and then use jQuery to pull out the numerical value and apply that to the character counter limiter.

`<textarea id="field1" class="input-xlarge limitChars" data-content="2000" rows="2" name="field1">` this field would have a limit of 2000 chars

`<textarea id="field2" class="input-xlarge limitChars" data-content="1000" rows="2" name="field2">` this field would have a limit of 1000 chars

`<textarea id="field3" class="input-xlarge limitChars" data-content="1500" rows="2" name="field3">` and this one would be 1500 chars.

From my other question's solution (see solution below), I'm assuming I'd need to pull out the data-content from the DOM and then apply that to the goal.  I just don't know how to pull out the value from data-content and would appreciate some help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".limitChars").each(function() {
        $(this).counter({
            goal: 500
        });
    });
});
```

=====================================================
With the extended dialog that occurred, I thought it might be helpful to show what I actually ended up with:

HTML

```
<textarea id="field1" class="input-xlarge" counter-limit="2000" rows="2" name="field1"> this field would have a limit of 2000 chars
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$("[data-counter-limit]").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this), limit = +$(this).data("counter-limit");
      $this.counter({
        goal: parseInt(limit,10)
        //  goal: limit
      });
});
```

Comment: target the elements through the class `.limitChars` and use `.data('content')` to get the value..

Comment: that is what I tried but I must have the syntax wrong.

Comment: `$(".limitChars").each(function() {
   console.log( $(this).data("content").val() );
   $(this).counter({
    goal: 500
   });
  });`

Comment: there is no `limit500` class in your examples, only `limitChars`. Also you need to remove the `.val()` as the `.data()` returns the value of the attribute directly.

Comment: original code and my comment have been updated to show limitChars instead of limit500.  .val() will be updated in a comment below.

Comment: `$(".limitChars").each(function() { console.log( $(this).data("content") ); $(this).counter({ goal: 500 }); });`  Are you saying I was close?

Comment: yes.. you just needed to replace the 500 you pass as `goal` to the value you got with `data()`.. (*and convert it to an actual number*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method to extract values from `data-` attributes. Then use [`parseInt(string, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert it to a number

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.limitChars').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.counter({
            goal: parseInt(self.data('content'),10)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting NaN so I `console.log( parseInt(self.data('data-counter-limit'),10) );` and it is returning the NaN reference.  I did change my data-content to data-counter-limit to be more clear.

Comment: ?why did you change the `data-content`. That is the attribute you have on your elements, so `.data('content')` will return its value. The `.data()` method understands the `data-*` attributes and gets its values but you need to exclude the `data-` part when accessing them.
So an attribute of `data-content` can be read with `.data('content')`

Comment: That was the problem.  I had `data-counter-limit` instead of just `counter-limit`.  I changed my textarea to data-counter-limit= so that when I see the code in another year, I'll know what it is about. LOL

Comment: I was actually reading that very same page/section but I didn't understand the examples. :( Now that my code is working, the examples are making more sense.  Thank you.

Comment: @dlackey, glad you got it sorted .. and yes sensible naming makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the classname `limit500` and use *only* a `data-*` attribute directly, `data-counter-limit`. It's cleaner than using both together.

```
<textarea data-counter-limit="1000">
```

```
$("[data-counter-limit]").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), limit = +$(this).data("counter-limit");
  $this.counter({
    goal: limit
  });
});
```

The selector `[data-counter-limit]` will obtain all the elements with an attribute `data-counter-limit`. The rest is a matter of parsing the limit and apply process the element.

Comment: Wrong, OP's using a class and a `data-*` attribute. He can drop the class

Comment: I forget about being able to define my own data-* attributes.  Thanks for that reminder.

Comment: @dlackey, no problem. I completed the edition of the post, now it looks as I wanted. Hope this help

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this page, this solution works, too.